# c++ error while compile application

Tags: c++, mysql, boost

i am using

boost and mysql connector in my application

when i try to compile application

i get this error

```
Error   4   error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
```

in config.h

```
#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
#include <inttypes.h>
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32)
#ifndef CPPCONN_DONT_TYPEDEF_MS_TYPES_TO_C99_TYPES

#if !defined(HAVE_INT8_T) && defined(HAVE_MS_INT8)
typedef __int8          int8_t;
#endif
```

i tried all the solutions i found while i searching on google
but nothing successed

hope i find a solution here

Thank you

Comment: Where and how is `HAVE_INT8_T` defined? In my `stdint.h`, the typededf for `int8_t` is guarded by `__int8_t_defined`, you could include that in your check.

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of `MSVC` does not have `<stdint.h>` so as a workaround some programmers do things in this way, but simplest workaround could be add `HAVE_STDINT_H` in to the definitions of the project or just define it before including the header